# Modifying the permalink href for posts with jquery

Tags: posts, permalinks, links

I Was wondering if there is any way to modify a link to add for example a category that I could use with $_GET.

For instance,
www.example.com/this-is-the-post/category (or ?cat=category)

I've tried to make a function in jquery to modify the link but it wont work. My best guess is that it has to do with the mod rewrite that wordpress uses.

```
            $('.post-style li a').each(function() {
                var oldHref = $(this).attr('href');
                $(this).attr('href', oldHref + '?cat=' + <?php echo $currentCat; ?>);
            });
```

$currentCat gets the page current category.

So I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction!

If anything is unclear, or needs to be added please comment and ill get on it asap!

Thanks

Comment: show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Milo Sure, I just edited it!

Comment: jQuery works in browser, I am not sure what it has to do with WP rewrite. Does your jQuery code works at all? What happens not how you expect it? Note that pure jQuery questions are better asked at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Rarst Well, what it does to the permalink href is nothing at all, nothing shows up except the actual permalink. So either the extra added link goes invisible or it wont work because wordpress wont allow it to be there is what im thinking.

Like I said, I believe it has something to do with wordpress, which makes it sort of eligible for wordpress answers, correct me if im wrong

Comment: WP (typically) is not really doing anything after the page has finished loading... I'd try Stack Overflow with this.